# reverse the order of elements in a list

Tags: java, list, reverse

Q: Given a list, reverse the order of its elements (don't use collections)

Here is my solution:

```
public static <T> void reverse(List<T> list) {
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        T t;
        t = list.get(0);
        list.remove(0);
        reverse(list);
        list.add(t);
    }
}
```

It is working as expected, but I want to know if this recursive method is an efficient way of reversing a list

Comment: You can't get more efficient in terms of time complexity, but you can probably make it faster. Use a profiler to figure out where most of the time is spent, and optimise that part of the code.

Comment: @DanielMesejo my doubts are about list.remove(0); , this will take O(N) if it is an ArrayList?

Comment: You could do it in O(N) (if it is an ArrayList) using `get` and `set`.

Comment: @DanielMesejo yes, i want to reverse the list in place

Comment: @ScottHunter Could you please please provide me an example? I want to make it work in O(N) for every type of list as input, not only for ArrayList

Comment: @CristianIacob You are going to need to test if it is an ArrayList or a LinkedList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reversing the list in place:

```
public static <T> void reverse(List<T> list) {
    int a =0, b = list.size()-1;
    while ( a < b ) {
        T a_val = list.get(a);
        list.set( a, list.get(b) );
        list.set( b, a_val );
        a++;
        b--;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if list is a LinkedList?

Comment: If list is a LinkedList the set operation has complexity O(n) ?

Comment: @Scott, you also can do `a++` and `b--` in the same lines as `list.set()`.

Comment: @ShreyGarg: Not a fan of modifying arguments in function calls.